# Как же правильно?

Tags: пунктуация

Оба варианта правильны?

> Много новостей у нас. Например, вчера падал-таки снег. Ещё: мне завтра надо идти в ВТБ-банк.

> Много новостей у нас. Например, вчера падал-таки снег. Ещё — мне завтра надо идти в ВТБ-банк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите пример из «Грамоты.ру»:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]